# Calculate duration startDate & endDate from an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

Im wondering if anyone can point me to some documentation on how to solve my issue.
Still new at native JS, and looking to do some date calculations.

Basically I need to calculate the duration between X and Y dates from and HTML forms input type date.

I have a rough sketch of my HTML and JS..
but still I cannot solve the issue without propper guidance and documentation.

```
       <div>
          <form>
              <label for="start-date"></label>
              <input type="date" id="start-date">

              <label for="end-date"></label>
              <input type="date" id="end-date">

              <label for="duration"></label>
              <input type="text" id="duration">
         </form>
       </div>
```

```
    const startDate = document.getElementById("start-date").value
    const endDate = document.getElementById("end-date").value
    let duration_from_form = document.getElementById("duration").value

    let duration = endDate - startDate;


    if (duration_from_form === ""){
        duration_from_form = duration;
    }
}
```

I know both of them a rough mockups and not ideal, but I'd love some help finding propper documentation on this matter.
Kind regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

If you want Date calculations and more documentation on how to play with dates then try this,
[Dates -JS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

But if you are looking to set the value in the field then

```
 document.getElementById("duration").value = duration
```

should be written in the onChange event of the field, more on that here
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the input, and the doc!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getTimeBetweenDates(e) {
  var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
  var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("date2").value);

  var diff;

  if (date1 < date2) {
    diff = new Date(date2 - date1);
  } else {
    diff = new Date(date1 - date2);
  }

  var years = (diff.getFullYear() - 1970);
  var months = diff.getMonth();
  var days = diff.getDate();

  var yearTxt = "year";
  var monthTxt = "month";
  var dayTxt = "day";

  if (years > 1) yearTxt += "s";
  if (months > 1) monthTxt += "s";
  if (days > 1) dayTxt += "s";

  if (years >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("showdiff").innerHTML = years + " " + yearTxt + ", " + months + " " + monthTxt + ", " + days + " " + dayTxt;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("showdiff").innerHTML = "Equal dates";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="" method="" onSubmit="event.preventDefault(); getTimeBetweenDates();">
  <input type="date" id="date1">
  <input type="date" id="date2">
</form>

<br>
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Send">Send</button>

<br>
<p id="showdiff"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how you can find your date difference with the help of Jquery**

```js
const setup = () => {
  let firstDate = $('#start-date').val();
  let secondDate = $('#end-date').val();
  const findTheDifferenceBetweenTwoDates = (firstDate, secondDate) => {
  firstDate = new Date(firstDate);
    secondDate = new Date(secondDate);
    
    let timeDifference = Math.abs(secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime());
    
    let millisecondsInADay = (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    
    let differenceOfDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference / millisecondsInADay);
    
    return differenceOfDays;
    
  }
  
  let result = findTheDifferenceBetweenTwoDates(firstDate, secondDate);
  $("#duration").val(result);  
  
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#start-date').change(function () {
    if($('#end-date').val()!='')
    {
      setup();
    }
  })
  $('#end-date').change(function () {
    if($('#start-date').val()!='')
    {
      setup();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: avenir;
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: avenir;
}

input:focus {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form>
        <label for="start-date"></label>
        <input type="date" id="start-date">

        <label for="end-date"></label>
        <input type="date" id="end-date">

        <label for="duration"></label>
        <input type="text" id="duration" placeholder="Difference">
   </form>
 </div>
```